# Always getting Bad Credential while communicating with LDAP

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, ldap, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

I am getting bad credentials while communicating with LDAP,

I have an Administrator user set up (and can log in to Windows Server 2012 with it fine) and have Active Directory Domain Services installed on the server OK.
I don't think so my application have any issue because it's working fine with .ldif file embedded spring, and i have also tried with the below open server and it is also working fine.

[LDAP_Server_Details](https://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/#comment-6791)

I am also sharing the DC Structure, if i am passing any wrong info from code then please correct me.

[image: DC_Structure]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Configuration

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)
        throws Exception {
    System.out.println(
            "WebSecurityConfig configure(HttpSecurity http)");
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
            .fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    System.out.println(
            "WebSecurityConfig configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)");
    auth.ldapAuthentication()
            .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=Users")
            //.groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
            .contextSource(contextSource()).passwordCompare()
            .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
            .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
}

@Bean
public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource() {
    System.out.println(
            "DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource()");
    return new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(
            Arrays.asList("ldap://test.local:389/"),
            "dc=test,dc=local");
}

}
```

Comment: Stack trace? Why are you taking about active directory when your question is about OpenLDAP?

Comment: i am taking an example for openLDAP, but our client have AD, where we have created some users but we are unable to connect with AD. telnet is reachable, connection is working. but giving Bed Credential exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if Active Directory is a kind of LDAP, the standard LDAP support (in Spring Security) does not work for it. Instead you should use the specialized *ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider*:

```java
@Bean
public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adProvider() {
    return new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("YOURDOMAIN", "ldap://test.local:389/");
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(adProvider());
}
```

Don't forget to change *YOURDOMAIN* to the domain you want to login to.